# Add class in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm programming an input site and want to highlight empty fields. I want to check if they're empty with an if statement and then add the class that Highlights them.

My code:

JS:

```
var hi = function () 
{
   if(document.getElementById('input1').value==="")
   {
      $('#input1').addClass('hi'); 
   };
});
```

I made it into a function so I can call it in the html file.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="ip" id="input1" placeholder="firstname">
```

to call the js:

```
<input type="button" onclick="dcc (); pwc (); hi();" value="Submit" id="button">
```

The different files(js and html are linked and working).

CSS:

```
.hi {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 0.01em;
  margin-right: 15em;
  margin-top: 1.05em;
  float: right;
}
```

My Problem is: Upon clicking the button nothing happens the other two functions were displayed (alerts telling the user that the chosen pw is too short) but when i linked the hi function they stopped working...
Any help would be greatly appreciated! If I described something too vague please ask and I will try to clarify!

Comment: A JSFiddle reproducing the problem would help us fix it

Comment: Always check your Javascript error console.  If there are no errors, you can put in `console.log` statements in your `hi` function to list out exactly what it is doing.  (Or, you could use your browser's debugger tools.)

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Thanks for the advice! Where exactly would I have to put the console.log Statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in `hi`:

```
});
```

^ remove the last paren.

In the future, open up your browser's console and check for errors like this - it makes debugging much easier.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9du3h/)

Alternatively, you could use an event handler for this:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    console.log(document.getElementById('input1').value);
    if (document.getElementById('input1').value === "") {
        $('#input1').addClass('hi');
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I´m new and learning :D I know that firebug is an addon but it is used in a similiar way right?

Comment: @user3466038 Yes!  Firefox has a basic console, as well as some excellent add-ons that help one debug.  If I answered your question, don't forget to upvote and accept!

Comment: The Problem now is my alert functions are working but the Input field isnt highlighted even if it is still empty... Could it be a Problem with calling the function in the html file?

Comment: @user3466038 That sounds like a separate question.

Comment: So you would say I should open a new one?

Comment: @user3466038 accept an answer for this one, and open a new one, yes.

Comment: @user3466038 Can you explain why you un-accepted my answer?

Comment: I tried to accept two answers but it seems that´s impossible... Is there any way I can do that or an equivalent of some sort to thank two People?

Comment: @user3466038 -- You accept one answer, then you can upvote any others you feel were helpful.  You can also upvote questions on other answers. To upvote, look at the number beside this post and click the up arrow above it.

Comment: @user3466038 Accept the best answer, then upvote the others that helped (like Jeremy mentioned).  Thankful comments are also nice!

Comment: Seems as if my Reputation score is too low to appreciate the help of all you other guys... Sorry :(

Comment: @user3466038 No worries!  You'll get there soon enough.  You get 2 rep for accepting, so you're already partway there?

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 Yeah now im at 3 :D Just started learning this was my first question ^^

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you have a syntax error in your JS.

```
var hi = function () { // cleaner to have the bracket here
   if(document.getElementById('input1').value==="") {
      $('#input1').addClass('hi'); 
   } // no semicolon
}; // no parenthesis
```

Also, instead of using `document.getElementById('input1').value`, use jQuery since you have it! `$('#input1').val()`.

Comment: Why does he have to use jQuery?

Comment: @hanleyhansen, he doesn't "have to", but if he already has jQuery referenced, it's bad practice to mix it with - in this sense - redundant native code.

Comment: @hanleyhansen And i didn't say he "has to".

Comment: @scimonster Thanks for the fast answer! I changed my code and now the js works again but it seems the class is not added. My Input field remains the same. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user3466038 Are you sure that the value is actually the empty string?

Comment: @scimonster I thought because there is no Input it should be empty and the condition is true and the class should be added. I got another js function that alerts if a field is left out i put in the same condition and this one works

Comment: Thats part of the function that does work:                          if (document.getElementById('input1').value==="")
alert("Somethings missing!");

Answer (score 0):

Per the OP's request --

This is where you could put console.log statements to track what is happening.

```
var hi = function () 
{
   console.log("'Hi' - Entering function");
   if(document.getElementById('input1').value==="")
   {
      console.log("'Hi' - Condition true - doing addClass");
      $('#input1').addClass('hi'); 
   };
   console.log("'Hi' - Leaving function");
}
```

Now, that said, I in reality I do things more like:

```
var hi = function () 
{
   console.log("'Hi1");
   if(document.getElementById('input1').value==="")
   {
      console.log("'Hi2");
      $('#input1').addClass('hi'); 
   };
    console.log("'Hi3");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try like,

```
function hi() 
{
   if(document.getElementById('input1').value==="")
   {
      $('#input1').addClass('hi'); 
   }
}
```

Comment: This completely doesn't matter, and you've even left the syntax error there.